# Will I need a Belgium work permit after Brexit? I have Dutch permanent residency. and I live in Netherlands

Tags: working-visas, netherlands, uk-citizens, brexit, belgium

I live in the Netherlands, I have a permanent resident permit in the Netherlands ( I am a British national).
I have worked in Belgium for 2 years as a full time employee.
Will I need a Belgium work permit after Brexit?

Comment: Are you living in the Netherlands and working in Belgien presently? If yes, then you will be a 'border worker'. This topic has been handled here on this site. You should first ask your employer, but if I remember correctly Belgium has a special visa for those 3rd country nationals who live outside but work inside Belgium.

Comment: Look at the comments of this question: **special work permit B** [working visas - Can I reside in Germany, in case I work for a Belgian company? - Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21057/can-i-reside-in-germany-in-case-i-work-for-a-belgian-company)